# Plotting the average pattern in grouped peaks in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm still not very good at wording these questions so sorry about that. I'm looking for suggestions on how to subset the data to analyse the peaks in the data and to plot the average pattern of the peaks, in particular in comparison to peaks in type="m1". If I were to plot the data now it'd show uncountable numbers of peaks, with peaks in "m1" significantly effecting peaks in the other types. The peaks occur in the column Hetero with the column Generations being the x-axis over which the peaks form.

```
Mut
# A tibble: 35,742 x 3
# Groups:   Generations [4,001]
  Generations type      Hetero
        <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>
1        2000 m10   0.0000682 
2        2000 m11   0.00000995
3        2000 m2    0.000743  
4        2000 m3    0.000518  
5        2000 m4    0.000185  
6        2000 m5    0.000616  
7        2000 m6    0.0000683 
8        2000 m7    0.00000498
9        2000 m8    0.0000294 
10        2000 m9    0.0000149 
# ... with 35,732 more rows
>
```

A sub optimal alternative would be to find the correlation between Hetero of "m1"  and each of the other types.
What I really want is the entire curve for each group leading up to and after a peak in m1.

```
structure(list(Generations = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2003), type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L), .Label = c("m10", "m11", 
"m2", "m3", "m4", "m5", "m6", "m7", "m8", "m9", "m1"), class = "factor"),         
Hetero = c(6.825e-05, 9.95e-06, 0.000742725, 0.0005181, 0.000185375, 
0.000615925, 6.83e-05, 4.975e-06, 2.935e-05, 1.4925e-05, 
3.94e-05, 9.9e-06, 0.000749025, 0.0005311, 0.00017085, 0.000629025, 
6.835e-05, 9.9e-06, 3.3775e-05, 1.4875e-05, 5.4125e-05, 0.000720775, 
0.000559525, 0.0001716, 0.000576175, 5.3875e-05, 4.975e-06, 
6.0775e-05, 4.975e-06, 4.91e-05)), row.names = c(NA, -30L
), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = 
"Generations", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
0:9, 10:19, 20:28, 29L), group_sizes = c(10L, 10L, 9L, 1L
), biggest_group_size = 10L, labels = structure(list(Generations = c(2000, 
2001, 2002, 2003)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame", vars = 
"Generations", drop = TRUE))
```

so this is an example to help visualise what I'm looking for, I'd want the average pattern of the blue line between each peak in the red line in this graph:

[image]

Comment: Are there multiple measurements of each level in `type`? Can you please provide a reproducible version of your data via `dput`

Comment: yes there are 11 measurements grouped by type for each generation and there are 4000 generations

Comment: I've added a dput thingy, hope it's useful